# how to get only contact numbers without using android widgets?

Tags: android

hi all below code giving me contact names and phone numbers from contact list  but i need only phone numbers how  can i solve the issue so give me solution with full details  without using android widget

```
public void getContacts(Context context){
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI));      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contactscontract api for that. For a reference on that api you can refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html][1](http://code.google.com/p/android-contacts-contract-example/)

For an example on how to use this api you can look at this example at google code http://code.google.com/p/android-contacts-contract-example/